# Homosexuality gay feeling

Tags: homosexuality

Please suggest any dua which will protect is to stay away from the thoughts of gay feeling , please, I am sure there must be some Quranic verse to keep away of from those shaitanic feeling?

Answer (score 1):

Homosexuality gay feeling is related to your lust *(nafsu)*. And the best way to control your sexual feeling is through fasting.

**Al-Baqarah, Verse 183 :**

> "O you who have believed, decreed upon you is **fasting** as it was
>   decreed upon those before you that you may become righteous"

Fasting will reward you with *Takwa* (fear of Allah) which will help you to control your feelings.

In addition, it is best for you to *Istighfar (Astaghfirullah)* whenever you have a thoughts or feeling of partaking in satanic activities.

Wallahualam.